# Mongo query Update year depends on the inner document field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my data. I wanted to change year but It should effective to only the first item of the document array

```json
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "62053aa8aa1cfbe8c4e72662"
        },
        "school": "Test",
        "reports": [
            {
            "year": "2020",     // This has to be changed to 2019
            "createdAt": {
                "$date": "2022-02-10T17:05:25.682Z"
            },
            "pid": {
                "$oid": "620545d5097761628f32365a"
            },
            "details": {
                "end_date": {
                    "$date": "2020-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"   // when end date is prior to July 01 of the $year mentioned.
                }
            }
        }, {
            "year": "2020",
            "createdAt": {
                "$date": "2022-03-14T19:08:38.125Z"
            },
            "pid": {
                "$oid": "622f92b68a408531d4b784de"
            },
            "details": {
                "end_date": {
                    "$date": "2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    }
```

In the above data, I want to reduce the year to the previous year, if details.end_date is prior to July 01 of the current mentioned year. But It should change only the first item of the embedded array.

For example,

```
If Year is 2020 and details.end_date is prior to 01-July-2020, then change the year to 2019

If Year is 2020 and details.end_date is after 01-July-2020, then do not change the year

If Year is 2021 and details.end_date is prior to 01-July-2021, then change the year to 2020

If Year is 2021 and details.end_date is after 01-July-2021, then do not change the year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. isolate the first elem of the `reports` array for easier processing using `$arrayElemAt`
2. use `$cond` to derive the year value with `$month`. Use `$toInt` and `$toString` for type conversion
3. use `$concatArrays` to append back the processed first Elem back to the reports array. Keep only the "tail" (i.e. without the first elem) using `$slice`
4. `$merge` to update the result back to the collection

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "firstElem": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$reports",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "firstElem.year": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $lt: [
              {
                "$month": "$firstElem.end_date"
              },
              7
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$toString": {
              "$subtract": [
                {
                  "$toInt": "$firstElem.year"
                },
                1
              ]
            }
          },
          "else": "$firstElem.year"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "reports": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            "$firstElem"
          ],
          {
            "$slice": [
              "$reports",
              1,
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  {
                    "$size": "$reports"
                  },
                  1
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      firstElem: false
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rpvj1usG1tC) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you. Will it update the db?

Comment: @SmithDwayne yes, the update is done through the last stage of `$merge`